# Wordpress header menu customisation

Tags: wordpress, nav

I have installed theme, and I desire to customize the header menu.
The structure of new header menu should be:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
    </a>
</div>
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
                         Page1                         
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
                         Page2                         
            </a>
        </li>
                ...

        <!-- Navbar Search -->
        <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="navbar-search">
            <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I was trying to solve it by using WP function:

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) { ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu clearfix', 'container' => '', 'walker' => new mts_menu_walker ) ); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <ul class="menu clearfix">
        <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
</nav>
```

Anyway, the result is poor, as WP produces new structure of the header menu and styles are no longer applied.

Thus I have several questions:

1. How to populate header menu elements with `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>` tag?
2. How to include  source for logo `<img src="img/logo.png">` with WP function?
3. How to include also  as header manu element include in li tag?
4. Or (instead of 1-3 questions) how to "translate" regular html above on wordpress html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to populate header menu elements with `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>` tag?

You can use the `link_before` parameter of [`wp_nav_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to display something before the text link. So your `wp_nav_menu` code will look like this:

```
<nav role="navigation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
        'container' => '',
        'menu' => __( 'Menu mobile', 'cicr' ),
        'menu_class' => 'menu clearfix',
        'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
        'before' => '',
        'after' => '',
        'link_before' => '<i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>',
        'link_after' => '',
        'walker' => new mts_menu_walker
    )); ?>
</nav>
```

If you need to add this icon only on certain links, I suggest to add a class on this link (in administration, click on "Screen options" on the top right then check "CSS classes" to displlay the class input), then in CSS add a pseudo element on those link to display the icon. It would look like something like this:

```
a.exclamation {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
a.exclamation:before {
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("images/exclamation.png") left top no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

> How to include source for logo `<img src="img/logo.png">` with WP function?

Place your logo in the image folder of your theme folder, then use the [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) function to get the URI of your theme folder.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" />
```

> How to include also as header manu element include in li tag?

Considering you're talking about the search navbar (not sure what you mean), you could make use of the `items_wrap` `wp_nav_menu` parameter:

```
'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">'.
                  '%3$s'.
                  '<li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="navbar-search">'.
                     '<a href="#">'.
                       '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>'.
                     '</a>'.
                  '</li>'.
                '</ul>',
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This line was also very helpful - menu_class' => 'menu clearfix', I added required class (not to rewrite css) and for icons just decided to install fon awesome plugin and put icons manually.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the function codex reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

You can use `before`and `after`parameters to apply `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>` before your link text. You can also use `link_before` and `link_after` parameters to place text before your link. If you need to wrap some code, you could use `items_wrap` parameters to pass the wrapper to the div menu itself.

To bring your uploaded WordPress logo (header on the customization page), you should try:

```
<img src="<?php echo( get_header_image() ); ?>" alt="<?php echo( get_bloginfo( 'title' ) ); ?>" />
```

You can use `container_class` and `menu_class` to customize the classes and apply styles to your `ul` and `li`. By default, WordPress returns a markup code with similar hierarchy: `div>ul>li>a`.

Hope it helps. The link I provided have full instructions for using the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now I better understand how to add classes for required tags